# Liquibase Precondition MARK_RAN Not Valid

Tags: xml, liquibase

I have the following changeset, using LiquiBase 3.5.1 (latest):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">

    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <sqlCheck expectedResult="2">SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo';</sqlCheck>
    </preConditions>
    <changeSet author="user" id="base">
        <sqlFile path="liquibase/base.sql"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Seems simply enough, right? The idea is that it checks to see if the DB is empty (checking for 2 tables for the Liquibase tables that are auto-generated) and if it is, run a base script. If it fails, however, it is supposed to mark the changeset as run and move along (documentation for the feature [here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html)). However, I get the following error:

```
Value 'MARK_RAN' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[HALT, WARN]'.
```

Comment: Checkout my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39223493/332248). Short answer: `MARK_RAN` is not available on the changelog level. Only on changesets.

Answer (score 4):

Liquibase distinguishes between preconditions at the changelog level
and Preconditions at the changeset level.
Outside a changeset (e.g. at the beginning of the change log), only HALT and WARN are possible values.

Look at the xsd  [schema](http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd)

There are two Types: onChangeSetPreconditionErrorOrFail and onChangeLogPreconditionErrorOrFail

You can just change your script as follows:

```
<changeSet author="user" id="base">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <sqlCheck expectedResult="2">SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo';</sqlCheck>
    </preConditions>
    <sqlFile path="liquibase/base.sql"/>
</changeSet>
```