# Value 'CONTINUE' is not facet-valid error on running liquibase

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase

When i try to run the following command:

```
java -jar liquibase-3.4.1.jar --classpath=postgresql-9.2-1004.jdbc4.jar --logLevel=severe --url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/raritan --username=<USER>--password=<PWD> --changeLogFile=master_changelog.xml update
```

I get the following exception:

```
    SEVERE 8/29/16 12:46 PM: liquibase: Error parsing line 7 column 35 of changelogdropViews.xml: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'CONTINUE' is not facet-valid withespect to enumeration '[HALT, WARN]'. It must be a value from the enumeration. liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: iquibase.exception.SetupException
 Error parsing line 7 column 35 of changelog_dropViews.xml: cvc-enumeration-val
d: Value 'CONTINUE' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[HALT, WARN
'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
```

This is my changelog file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

    <preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
            <sqlCheck expectedResult="1">select count(1) from pg_extension where extname='plsh'</sqlCheck>
    </preConditions>
```

Comment: What exactly is the content of `changelog_dropViews.xml`? Also: your pre-condition doesn't really make sense as you still proceed with creating everything even if `plsh` is not installed - you can actually just remove that precondition.

Comment: In addition to above mentioned contents it contains:                                             changeSet author="***" id="***">
    <sql>
 //query
    </sql>
</changeSet>                                                                                                       I am using this pre condition to check if the machine is windows or linux, because some queries run in shell and will fail in windows, so want to skip it

Comment: CONTINUE skips the changeSet if preCondition fails

Comment: The fact that you get the error means, that Liquibase does try to create those `plsh` functions

Answer (score 7):

See the documentation for preconditions: 
http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html

There it says:

> Outside a changeset (e.g. at the beginning of the change log), only HALT and WARN are possible values.